# Remove index.php from url and still be able to POST

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, post, url-rewriting

I am redirecting requests to index.php with .htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works fine but the problem is forms are not able to POST anymore.

How can I hide index.php from the url while still being able to POST forms.

Comment: the forms are posting to self <form name='example' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post' >

Comment: care to elaborate? all my forms are in a header page which is included in every page on the website...

Comment: the 301 redirect (really any redirect) will kill your post variables. Perhaps post to `str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` or even simpler, when posting to self you can post to just `?` which the browser will just interpret as self client side. It will add a `?` to the url. or maybe `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: got it working with str_replace, thanks

Comment: created an answer in case you want to accept and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 301 redirect (really any redirect) will kill your post variables. Perhaps post to `str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` or even simpler, when posting to self you can post to just `?` which the browser will just interpret as self client side. It will add a `?` to the url. or maybe `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.